# Strut: customizing fielderror tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

In my jsp file I have the following line:

```
<tr><td><s:fielderror/></td></tr>
```

This display the error in default black color. Any idea how to change the color of the fielderror messages to let's say red and present them in a highlighted format?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td style="color:blue;background-color:yellow;">
        <s:fielderror/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: This could also be done with an anchor element `<a style="color:blue;background-color:yellow;"><s:fielderror/></a>`